# In Visual Studio, my Design view doesn't load the master page controls. Why?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, hresult, design-view

It's just so much `HRESULT E_FAIL`, if you know what I'm talking about.

And if you use Visual Studio, you know what I'm talking about.

Similar thread, but not a duplicate: [Is the design view for aspx pages in Visual Studio useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196001/is-the-design-view-for-aspx-pages-in-visual-studio-useful)

Any insight, including input from Microsoft MVPs (oh, I know you're out there) would be super cool.

Comment: Maybe it can't find the controls in design view.  Are the pages/controls in different directories?

Comment: That's likely. I've thankfully transitioned to the wonderful world of MVC and this is not and never will be (hopefully) a concern of mine again.

Answer (score 3):

There could be some possible reasons.

1st is if you have created a web form (aspx) page Nested it with Master Page;
and on the child page you registered a control where you have develop your page.

in short I want to say that.

You nested your child page in the Master page but on that child page you only registered some controls and nothing else. 
So you can view the master page only on that child page.

You can't see the master page on the controller pages.

Because Controller pages are just partial pages so they don't load the master page.

Master Page <- Child Page <- Registered a control on child page

```
<%@ Register Src="Ctrl_AdminReports.ascx" TagName="Ctrl_AdminReports" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
```

you can only access the master page controls on its direct child.

Comment: Can you tell me what you have written on the top of your Nested Page?

Answer (score -3):

Try this:
Put your MasterPages in a seperate folder (if they aren't already.  Call it `masterpages`.  Then add this to your `web.config`:

```
<location path="MasterPage">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

This will allow anonymous access to that folder and allow access to the masterpage.  Also, are these nested masterpages?

Comment: Are you sure the web.config has any bearing on how the design view works? Sounds iffy.