# ASP.net writing code behind variable to HTML page code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hey all i am trying to get this:

```
<div id="subpg_main">    
<%= theHeadering %>
</div>
<!-- END BODY PAGE ------------------------->
```

To work within my HTML code.

The code behind just has this:

```
Public Class thankyou
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Public theHeadering As String = ""

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim theName As String = "Bob Barker"
        Dim theEmail As String = "bobb@thepriceisright.com"

        If theForm = "contact" Then
            theHeadering = "<H1>Thank you " & theName & " for contacting us!</H1><BR />"
            theHeadering += "We will be contacting you via your email address at " & theEmail & " within 24 hours."
        End If
    End Sub    
End Class
```

However, when i run the page i get the following error:

**Compiler Error Message: BC30451: 'theHeadering' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.**

Comment: Did you forget to compile after adding the field?

Comment: running it in debug mode, @HackedByChinese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
 Public Property theHeadering As String = ""
```

And not:

```
 Public theHeadering As String = ""
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a function and call it from the HTML

```
<div id="subpg_main">    
<%= TheHeadering()%>
</div>
<!-- END BODY PAGE ------------------------->



Public Class thankyou
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private headering As String = ""

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim theName As String = "Bob Barker"
        Dim theEmail As String = "bobb@thepriceisright.com"

        If theForm = "contact" Then
            headering = "<H1>Thank you " & theName & " for contacting us!</H1><BR />"
            headering += "We will be contacting you via your email address at " & theEmail & " within 24 hours."
        End If
    End Sub    
    Public Function TheHeadering() As String
        Return headering
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Error in code **theHeading is already declared as private theHeading As String**

Comment: Did you compile before testing? I have just created a website with this code and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

open the designer page `page.aspx.designer.vb`

and add:

`Protected theHeadering As String`

you will now have everything working.

This is done automatically, but sometimes, the automatic part can fail.

---

Here is an example creating an empty WebForms project. [Full image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0Y6n.png).

[image]

Comment: then it's something wrong with your compilation part, just created a new **VB.NET Webforms** project and wrote what you see, and works as you can see.

Comment: Isn't making changes to the designer file a bad idea?

Comment: @ShaiCohen not if you know what you're doing :)

Comment: I don't like what you are insinuating .... but then again 23.8k vs 1k :) Seriously though, doesn't VS automatically write to that file and thus can overwrite any change you make? Or, more importantly, it signals that something is "corrupt" with the solution/project?

Comment: @ShaiCohen it's a merely helper file that holds the variables in use, when you normally drag and drop controls directly to the visual page (and I stop doing that several years ago - [the visual thingy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/196129/28004)). It helps to track those objects, and I have plenty old projects that when I need a new user control or a merely string to hold a variable I do need to add it to the `designer` page before I can compile.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

**EDIT**

**HTML** CODE

```
<div id="subpg_main">    
<%# TheHeadering()%>
</div>
<!-- END BODY PAGE ------------------------->


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim theName As String = "Bob Barker"
    Dim theEmail As String = "bobb@thepriceisright.com"

    If theForm = "contact" Then
        theHeadering = "<H1>Thank you " & theName & " for contacting us!</H1><BR />"
        theHeadering += "We will be contacting you via your email address at " & theEmail & " within 24 hours."
    End If
   'Bind your expression with the markup code
   Me.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: @StealthRT you have to replace = for #

Comment: Changed to **<%# theHeadering()%>** and now it says **Argument not specified for parameter 'index' of 'Public ReadOnly Default property Chars(index as Integer) As Char**

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the Page Directive of the Mark up code is pointing to another class which the have the same property 
         theHeadering As String = ""
but its not a Public access level.